# Angular how do I resolve Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'catalog/test'?

Tags: javascript, angular, url, path, routes

There is a route:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'catalog', component: DiskComponent},
    {path: 'catalog/**', component: DiskComponent},
]
```

The path http://localhost:4200/catalog works, but when I open http://localhost:4200/catalog/test I get the error:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'catalog/test'

How do I resolve it?

Comment: It should be {path: 'catalog/:name', component: DiskComponent}, 'name' being your parameter name

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid thank you it works!

Comment: Glad to know. I've added the same as the answer. Appreciate if you could mark the answer as accepted as it would help other community members as well who are looking for similar answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route should be configured as below.

```
{path: 'catalog/:name', component: DiskComponent}
```

':name' stands for the name of the parameter and can be accessed in the component via 'ActivatedRoute'.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params["name"]); //Output would be 'test' in your case
  });
}
```

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-mu7m5m?file=app/views/catalog/catalog.component.ts